# Excel - Red Cross where a drop down list should be

Tags: vba, excel-2003, office-2003

anyone shed any light as to why this might be happening for one user but not another.

Excel 2003 Macro security is set to low; spreadsheet is not read only.

Everywhere where there is supposed to be a drop down list, instead of that there is a box with a red cross in it.

Kind Regards,

Jim

Comment: What kind of drop down list? ActiveX control, Forms control, data validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure it's not a difference in Tools > Add-Ins.

The only other thing that occurs to me is checking Tools > Protection, but the description doesn't seem to suit this.

What may help is more thinking about which users can, which can't.